# Can I increase root partition with this current partition

Tags: linux, partition

I am using arch-linux dual-boot windows currently on Asus ZenBook UX305 Laptop with 256 GB memory.
I have approximately 70GB given to linux and rest to windows. I need to install a software which needs 17GB memory free and I prefer installing it in my linux os, but as you would have guessed I dont have enough space. My root has ~13 GB free while my home has ~16 GB free and Windows has enough free space.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W80Rl.png) is screenshot of GParted partition window.

> Device--------Size----Used---Unused--% Used---Mount Point
>
> /dev/sda5----42G----28G----12G-------70%-------/
>
> /dev/sda6----26G----8.8G---16G-------36%-------/home
>
> /dev/sda4----162M--49M----114M-----30%-------/boot
>
> /dev/sda3----167G--148G---19G------ 89%-------/run/media/naman/OS

Is it possible to resize my root partition for the partition table to install the big software in linux partition (even bit unsafe method?!).

Comment: there's no need for a remotely hosted image when text will do (for reasons why, see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  copy and paste the output of `fdisk` into your question.

Comment: please add the fdisk output even though i've answered your question already.  the question (and answer) is useless to anyone else without that information.   someone may come up with a better answer than mine anyway.

Comment: thanks, but that's incomplete.  try `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main windows partition (`/dev/sda3`) has ~18GB free, but it's a primary partition while your linux partitions are in extended partitions. 
 Without a complete backup, repartition, reformat and restore, the only way to do it with your current disk layout is to:

- Move your `/home` directory into the `/` partition (there's more than enough space for it).  This should be done in single-user mode (or, at least, while only root is logged in and nothing is writing to any file under /home).

  For example:

  ```
  umount /home
  mkdir /home.old
  mount /dev/sda6 /home.old
  mv /home /home.old
  rsync -a /home.old/ /home/
  umount /home.old
  ```
- Edit `/etc/fstab` and comment-out or delete the line for `/home`.
- Delete the `/home` partition (`/dev/sda6`)
- Extend the `/` partition (`/dev/sda5`) so that it takes up all the free space that used to be /`dev/sda6`.
- Grow the `/` filesystem with `resize2fs`

If you use `gparted`,  the final three steps can be done in one easy operation.